# Java simple ship game, initialize board

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple game ships. I have a `Ship` class in which I initialize coordinates, length, and direction.

```
public class ship{

    byte x,y;   

    byte []length;
    boolean direction; 


    public ship(byte x, byte y, byte length, boolean direction)
    {
        this.x=x;  
        this.y=y;
        this.length=new byte [length];  
        this.direction=direction;  
    }
}
```

And my function that initiates ships.

```
public class board{


    Random r=new Random();
    byte arr[][]=new byte[10][10];
    byte listlenght[]={2,2,3,3,4};
    okret shiplist[]=new ship[listlenght.length];

    void init() {

        for (int i = 0; i < shiplist.length; i++) {

            byte x, y;
            boolean direction;
            x = (byte) r.nextInt(10);
            y = (byte) r.nextInt(10);
            direction= r.nextBoolean();

            shiplist[i] = new ship(x,y,listlenght[i],direction);

        }
    }
}
```

My question is how I should create a board to add ships. Eg. A 10x10 two-dimensional array? How to solve it? I would then check whether the ship was placed on the board or not.

Comment: what are you doing with the ships after they are on the board?

Comment: I want to write a function that sank the ship. Ultimately, all I want to present graphically.

Comment: There's multiple ways to model this.

Comment: You can make a suggestion?

Comment: One way would be to add another class `Field` which will be one field on your board. It will have an attribute `contains` of type `Ship`. If that is null, there is no ship there. Now you just have to create the 2D array with new `Field`s (best: create a class `Board` that does it for you). Then create a new `Ship` with your desired properties and insert it in a random `Field` on your `Board`, in a random orientation, where it has enough room.